# Why calling this array from another class give me NPE?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 classes `NewAray` and `Disp`.

I have a 3D array initialized in  `NewAray` class :

```
array3D= new int[][][]
{

{

{1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
.....
.....
```

Which works fine and I am able to print it correctly.But when I created an object of 
`NewAray` class inside `Disp` , and print it, gives me a `NullPointerException`:

```
NewAray aObj=new NewAray();
System.out.print(aObj.array3D[0][p][q]); //throws NPE
```

or

```
 System.out.print(aObj.array3D[0][0][0]);
```

In `Disp` class. Why? How to resolve this?

**EDIT : Code of NewAray class as requested :**

```
   public class NewAray {

   static public int[][][] array3D;
    public static void main(String... a)
{
array3D= new int[][][]
{

{

{1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
}
};


int i,j,k;
  for(i=0; i<1; i++){
  for(j=0; j<8; j++){
  for (k=0; k<8; k++ )
  {
      System.out.print(array3D[i][j][k]);

  }
  System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
  }

}
}
```

Comment: Please post full source code of the NewArray class, we can't see how and where you are initializing the array.

Comment: Can you Show more code please. Class `NewAray`

Comment: You're only initializing the array in your `main` method... if you come in through a *different* `main` method, then it will still be null... Ideally, post a short but complete example demonstrating the problem (a 1x1 array would be fine...)

Comment: You should use a static initialization block.

Comment: How do you "call" an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
static public int[][][] array3D;
public static void main(String... a)
{
    array3D= new int[][][]
{ // data
```

With:

```
static public int[][][] array3D = new int[][][]
{ // data
```

At the moment you only initialize the data within the `main` method, and that isn't called if you use a `main` method somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

`array3D` must be instanciated when `NewAray` is constructed:

```
public class NewAray {
    static public int[][][] array3D = {...};
    // + main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the array is not yet initialized. You are initializing it in main(), which doesn't get called in the Disp class.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points to consider to resolve and clean your code:

- If array is specific to individual object of class NewArray, make it as an instance variable. Otherwise make it as class variable using static.
- If you want to access an instance variable in another class, better to have getter method in class NewArray.

  `public int getVal(int dim1, int dim2, int dim3) {
    return this.array3D[dim1][dim2][dim3]
  }`
- Remember one java application will have only one main（） method as the starting point.

Even if it is a homework problem, clean code avoids many issues.